# How to update and change the current domain array list

Tags: python, arrays, string, jupyter

For example i have a list of website name examples

```
exist = ['http://sushiblast.com', 'http://funnyvideos-funny.info', 'https://youtube.com','https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/minecraft']
```

Here is the code example that i used

```
input_str = exist
   
# Printing original string  
print ("Original string: " + input_str) 
   
result_str = "" 
   
for i in range(5, len(input_str)): 
    if i != 1: 
        result_str = result_str + input_str[i] 
   
# Printing string after removal   
print ("String after removal of i'th character : " + result_str)
```

In this one i tried to erase the https from the name list but, it doesn't work with an array list.

Is there a way where i could erase the `http://` and `https://` from the array list while also changing the url example from `'https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/minecraft'` to `my.forms.apps/minecraft`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

input_str = ['http://sushiblast.com', 'http://funnyvideos-funny.info', 'https://youtube.com','https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/minecraft']
   
result_str = []
   
for i in input_str: 
    url = re.compile(r"https?://")
    url = url.sub('', i)
    if '/' in url:
        url = url.split('/')[0] + '/' + url.split('/')[-1]
    result_str.append(url.replace('api', 'my'))
   
print (result_str)
```

Output:

```
['sushiblast.com', 'funnyvideos-funny.info', 'youtube.com', 'my.forms.app/minecraft']
```

Comment: if i were to replace the last api from `api.forms.app/minecraft` to `api.forms.app/minecraft` can i do this `print(result_str(txt.replace("api", "my"))` @Aymen?